# Typescript, how to reassign type after filtering by prop existance?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an array with:

```
const list: Readonly<ListProps> = {some values}

interface ListProps {
  type: 'radio' | 'check';
  style: 'text' | 'button';
  options: OptionProps[];
}

interface OptionProps {
  label: string;
  value: string;
  sublist?: ListProps;
}
```

I filtered out `options` to only leave those with `sublist`:

```
const nodesWithSublist: ListNodeWithSublist[] = list.options.filter(
    (style: OptionProps) => style.sublist,
  );
interface ListNodeWithSublist {
  label: string;
  value: string;
  sublist: ListProps;
}
```

I get error saying that `OptionProps[]` can't be assigned to `ListNodeWithSublist[]` because `sublist` can't be `undefined`. But since I filtered results to have only nodes with `sublist`, I think it would be right to assign array to `ListNodeWithSublist`. How to handle this?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44866

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, a limitation of TypeScript at the moment, see [issue #42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384), which is a suggestion for new behavior:

> Typescript should be able to infer the type of an object, if a type guard was checked on a property of the said object. Currently, Typescript does correctly infer the type of the property, but not its parent object.

Until/unless that's implemented, you can define your own [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) instead:

```typescript
function hasSublist(option: OptionProps): option is ListNodeWithSublist {
    return typeof option.sublist !== "undefined";
}
```

...and then use it in that code (it also means you can leave off the type annotation, since it's inferred from the result of the `filter`):

```typescript
const nodesWithSublist = list.options.filter(hasSublist);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3hAlpgXPAEohTCoQCeAPADJ4YAKMSADmgHwDcAUDzigwgYAMyhgE9TMzZp4Abx7xl8DJVYhCAIhhkcSLfAA+8LWAAW4ANZbeK+JkoRNpoQA8Mhk1oBGAVwwMVFslFTYMfXRCAHlWCNQZdgBtAF1eAF8+ASFRcQRY+JREuUV7aB8QCEJMGAEAczsVADcoCD8XGvrG5TQ-H1xMAH5CKSYWdgy+ET8UMEL4cyg0AGU+gYwACnDImLjI4oBKQm3UeDx4UYA5JFAAdRwMc1X+hgVQ5TgMPxgUVXUQJAieAnFAAOl6L0w8AAhABeWGmGagEQCEDAEKZHjIdBYFA3EBoe6PZ7reAI9agkFoUEoiA5DaLFZrBgHXjYtBIZygiBIOobPGgQkPJ7MzBJAAMKXBoowrJ4AHp5fZlSrVWqAHqDLKCYRiCQXBjXO7CkmvUoqcqVaoYWooBrveAtNodG1dB0Q9YjBjFDJAA)